# What Eclipse GEF software package contains Draw2d?

Tags: eclipse, draw2d

I'm trying to get the Eclipse GEF package "Draw2d".

What Eclipse GEF software package contains Draw2d? When I search for it, nothing appears in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following update site.

You can either use one of the **[following](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/updates/index.php)** update sites :

```
Nightly (not promoted to download.eclipse.org): https://hudson.eclipse.org/hudson/job/gef-master/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/update-site/ and https://hudson.eclipse.org/hudson/job/gef-maintenance/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/update-site/
Releases: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/gef/updates/releases/
Milestones: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/gef/updates/milestones/
Integration and Maintenance: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/gef/updates/interim/
```

If you fancy using the entire P2 Repo or the dropin, You could download them from here : 
http://www.eclipse.org/gef/downloads/

What happens when you use the `http://download.eclipse.org/tools/gef/updates/releases/` update site ? Does it list D2D ?

**Update**

The GEF `All-in-one` SDK can be installed since it contains Draw2D also like so :

[image]

Comment: It says that is already included. nitind from irc.freenode.net's #eclipse room says that this package is part of GEF SDK. Done.

Comment: @NicholasDiPiazza, ah ! You beat me to it :).

Comment: @NicholasDiPiazza, please consider accepting my answer so that it's helpful for other folks in the future.